# How do I return a value from a generic function as an implementation of a protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I want to build a map of protocols to objects that implement these protocols.  Then I want to be able to get an implementation for a given protocol.

This is what I've got so far:

```
class Services {
  var map = NSMapTable(keyOptions: .CopyIn, valueOptions: .WeakMemory)

  func register<T>(type: T, target: AnyObject) {
    map.setObject(target, forKey: String(type))
  }

  func get<T>(type: T) -> AnyObject {
    guard let target = map.objectForKey(String(type)) else {
      fatalError("Not registered")
    }
    return target
  }
}
```

And I can call it like this:

```
protocol Foo {
  func qux()
}

class Bar: Foo {
  func qux() {}
} 

services.register(Foo.self, target: Bar())
```

And that's great.  But when I want to retrieve it:

```
let foo: Foo = services.get(Foo.self)
```

... the above line generates an error:

> Foo.swift:12:34: Cannot convert call result type 'AnyObject' to expected type 'Foo'

How can I specify the generic function `get` returns an object that implements the protocol referenced in `T`?

I would like to avoid having to cast at the call.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this can fit for your purpose, but you can write something like this:

```
class Services {
    var map = NSMapTable(keyOptions: .CopyIn, valueOptions: .WeakMemory)

    func register<T>(type: T.Type, target: T) {
        guard let object = target as? AnyObject else {
            fatalError("Cannot register")
        }
        map.setObject(object, forKey: String(type))
    }

    func get<T>(type: T.Type) -> T {
        guard let target = map.objectForKey(String(type)) as? T else {
            fatalError("Not registered")
        }
        return target
    }
}
```

Comment: @i_am_jorf, may depend on many things. But I can assure you `services.register(Foo.self, target: Bar())` above works as expected with your class and protocol. Please try.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that you want to avoid the downcast but I think you should use:

```
if let foo: Foo = services.get(Foo.self) as? Foo {

}
```

since in your case a `protocol Foo: class` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What about making `get` return the generic type, you don't even need a type parameter because you already have it:

```
func get<T>() -> T {
    guard let target = map.objectForKey(String(T.self)) else {
        fatalError("Not registered")
    }
    return target as! T // or you could make the return type an Optional if you want to allow getting a service that wasn't registered.
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
let foo: Foo = services.get()
```